# How to display a variable from another class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

SetScoringTableViewController.h:

```
@interface SetScoringTableViewController : UITableViewController 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name1;
@end
```

SetScoringTableViewController.m:

```
@implementation SetScoringTableViewController
@synthesize name1;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

    name1 = @"Hello World"
}
```

GameDetailsTableViewController.m

```
  if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {

    SetScoringTableViewController *setScoring = [[SetScoringTableViewController alloc]init];

    static NSString *CellIdentifer1 = @"GameDetailsSetScoringCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer1];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:0];


    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @" %@", setScoring.name1];

            return cell;
}
```

When I try to run it, all I get is null. Can you please help me find how to display "Hello World" on my label. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `viewDidLoad` method is probably not called yet. Override the `init` method on your `SetScoringTableViewController` and set the value there:

```
- (instancetype)init {
   if (self = [super init]) {
       _name = @"Hello World";
   }
   return self;
}
```

Why would you instantiate a view controller from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? It's being dealloc-ed immediately after.

Answer (score 1):

When you call setScoring.name1 in your GameDetailsTableViewController.m you are calling a property of an object that you've just created in `SetScoringTableViewController *setScoring = [[SetScoringTableViewController alloc]init];`. Your `viewDidLoad` have never been executed, or even if it was, `setScoring` is another instance of `SetScoringTableViewController` class.

You first need to assign some value to name1 before call it. For example:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {

SetScoringTableViewController *setScoring = [[SetScoringTableViewController alloc]init];

static NSString *CellIdentifer1 = @"GameDetailsSetScoringCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer1];
label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:0];

setScoring.name1 = @"Hello World"

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @" %@", setScoring.name1];

        return cell;
}
```

Now your label will have the correct text. But in this case it just doesn't make any sense at all. Perhaps I could provide you a better explanation if you describe what exactly you are trying to do.